# RegRU домен, прикрепить к goDaddy

Tags: домен, ns

купил домен на regru, пытаюсь прикрепить его к хостингу godaddy, не могу разобраться как, где на хостинге godaddy найти инфу о NS? Вообще непонятно

Comment: https://www.reg.ru/support/dns/DNS-servery/kak-propisat-DNS-dlya-domena-v-lichnom-kabinete

Comment: А что вы понимаете под словом "хостинг" ? NS сервера и хостинг для сайта - обычно разные вещи. Вы берете у godaddy именно NS сервера или место для сайта ? Если первое - то конечно надо узнать у них адреса NS серверов. Если второе - то ip адрес на котором поднят ваш сайт и указывать его в "A" записи домена на основных NS серверах

Comment: [Find my GoDaddy nameservers](https://ru.godaddy.com/help/find-my-godaddy-nameservers-12318)